# Casting to class extending a class

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to fetch a class via name. I know that this class will extend my Event class. For further generic things I need the system to know that the class is a child class of Event. With Java I would probably cast it to something like `Class<? extends Event>`, but how do I do this with Kotlin?
My current code is:

```
Class.forName(eventClass) as Class<Event> // The as should cast to Class extending Event
```

I tried things like T: Event or ?: Event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kotlin equivalent of `Class<? extends Event>` is [`Class<out Event>`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#use-site-variance-type-projections).

Answer (score 0):

Using [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) would work just fine, as long as the JVM is your target, which the following short example demonstrates:

```
open class Foo
class Bar: Foo()

fun main() {
    val c = Class.forName("fullpackagepath.Bar")
    println(c.superclass == Foo::class.java) // true
}
```

Comment: `is Class<Foo>` returning `true` is 1) meaningless because of type erasure; 2) inserted by the compiler because of the static type (change all `<Foo>` to `<String>` and you'll get the same result).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov you are completely right. what is actually happening is `c as Class<*>` and `casted is Class<*>`... I have to admit that I was confused by the inferred type (shown as hint) for `casted`, which is `Class<Foo>` and not `Class<*>`, but the uncheck cast warning should have cleared that up.